# Inconsistent result between HERE maps display and places API

Tags: here-api

After changing street number coordinates in HERE Map creator 2 months ago, I have an inconsistent result between map and API (I don't know when changes have been approved though).

ie. "139 avenue Daumesnil Paris" is displayed at ~[48.84285,2.38459] but the autocomplete gives the original location [48.843868,2.38255]

Any idea of what's happening ? Some cache ?

Comment: Can you please share the request call ?

Comment: Of course (app id & code have been removed):
https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=48.858211%2C2.338757&q=139+Avenue+Daumesnil%2C+Paris&app_id=XXXX&app_code=XXXX

Answer (score 0):

In case you are finding any inconsistencies with the data, please refer following 2 options :

1) Use Map creator (locate the poi and make the change, Here team will review and approve it) : https://mapcreator.here.com/

2) Use Map Feedback API : https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html